# Unable to set breakpoints in EPIC (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, epic

I have installed Epic and Eclipse (I have never used them before). Whenever I try to set a breakpoint, I always get this error:

> "An internal error occurred during: "Toggle Line Breakpoint (epic)"(Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException)"

I have updated Eclipse to 3.4.1.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party. Hopefully this helps someone in the future. I got the same error with the latest version, Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). It was user error in my case, and I'm guessing yours too.

You need to create a new project or open an existing one and then add your Perl script to that project. Then everything should work fine.